# How to set different navigationbar color for different UIViewcontroller in xib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, uicolor

Iam trying to set different UINavigationBar color for different UIViewController in project.Till now i tried following code in ViewdidAppear methode of each UIViewController class and its not working still the color of navigationbar is not changing.

```
UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redbar.png"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Please help me

Comment: Change navigation bar color in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor: [UIColor redColor]];
```

Or, on iOS 6,

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

If you have a navigation controller as rootViewController, get it with:

```
    UINavigationController* nc = (UINavigationController*)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController;
```

And then set the color:

```
[nc.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

And if you want to change the color in each viewcontroller, just put the code in each `viewWillAppear` method

If you don't want to override the `viewWillAppear`in every viewcontroller, you can create a super viewcontroller for your project. But if it's too late, you can also create a custom `UINavigationController` and simply override push/pop methods like:

```
-(void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
    [self.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Do this for the four methods:

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Or at least for the methods you use.
And then override `viewWillAppear` in your viewControllers which need another bar color.

Comment: not working,in my home page am using image in uinavigationbar?is that the reason?

Comment: is there a way to set a default navigation bar color and then only change it in a few UIViewControllers?  I tried setting a default of blue in the AppDelegate, then in one of my ViewControllers I set the color to red....the problem is that when I go back, the navigation bar stays red...I want it to return to blue.  Any ideas?

Comment: You mentioned using viewWillAppear.  This will require making changes to every UIViewController....or using a base class for all UIViewControllers.  Is there no way to create the concept of a default value and then only override that in a few special cases?

Comment: I use to have a super viewcontroller in my apps to manage this kind of things (you set the right color int its viewwillappear and only override when you want to). But you can also override the navigationcontroller, see my new update.

Comment: Worked for me in just 2 Sec. THanks HeRo.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that  you want to set color in **storyboard**, not in *code*.

[image]

and then, open the **attribute inspect**,

[image]

try different **bar tint** or change its **back image** will work.

Comment: my mistake iwant todo it in xib

Answer (score 3):

Swift:

Global:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.RGB(197, 104, 66)
```

For each UIViewController:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.RGB(197, 104, 66)
}
```

Comment: There's no RGB color property, and you can't pass ints

Comment: @lan Bell, it's a method i added by myself, but not hurts for this question : )

Comment: Thanks! This code works well for me - but i would recommend the example be something like "self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red" and not use a custom method personally.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the solutions will give you a blink effect while changing background color as you are setting colors on `viewWillAppear`.

A solution without having blink effect is by setting the navigation bar color for each view controller in `viewDidLoad` and then changing the background color before navigation as below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.showGrayNavigationBar()
}
```

And then find the previous view controller and set the background color before viewAppears as :

```
override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
    let count =  self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count
    let vc = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[count! - 2]
    if vc is ServicesViewController{
        vc!.showGrayNavigationBar()
    }else if vc is ServiceDetailsViewController{
        vc!.showBlueNavigationBar()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a UINavigationController as your root view, you have to use the following method on the ViewWillAppear method :

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

It will change your current `UIViewController` navigationbar color :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement in previews controller to make navigation bar clear color:

   ```
   -(void)viewdidload{
       [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[XXXImage imageWithColor:[UIColor clearColor]] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Set custom view in the same frame of navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.2

```
 func navigationCtrl(){


            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()

            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "close_icon"), style: .Done, target: self ,action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissAction(_:)) )
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.IRANSansWeb(UIFont.IRANSansWebType.Medium, size: 20) , NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
        }
```

Comment: better adding some explanation how you have solved the problem of OP.